# PICamera white balance difference between preview and capture

Tags: python, picamera

Below is a screen shot of the preview and the captured image of the same scene taken from a single PICamera at the same time. As you can see the one on the left (the capture) is noticeably bluer than the one on the right (the preview).

Does anyone know what I need to do to get those two to match? When I capture an image, I want it to look exactly like the preview.

Here is the python code that created the preview and captured the image.

```
from picamera import PiCamera
import time

camera = PiCamera (resolution = (648, 484))
camera.preview_fullscreen = False
camera.start_preview (window = (633, 245, 648, 484))
time.sleep (10)
camera.capture ('test.png')
time.sleep (30)
camera.stop_preview
camera.close()
```

[image: Capture and Preview ScreenShot]

Comment: try turning off the AWB